# Scaling database storage capacity horizontally

Tags: database

Here's my question:

Database usually saves data into disk, may it be SQL or NoSQL database this is the most common. However in a cloud environment, machines typically are shipped with just an ample amount of storage, and as the application is used this can get used up and will become a problem, and although vertically scaling the storage (adding more disks, e.g. mounts) I understand in my case that **vertical scaling is not a long term solution**.

1. What is the best *scale out* solution for databases?

Given for example when ordering cloud machines you get typically just enough disk for each machine, 50GB for instance.

So if we're targeting 1TB minimum capacity for we will need to run like 20 machines? for 10TB capacity like ten times more machine?

2. How do you from day one make use of a scalable database without worrying on running out of disk space? (*I mean given that you can spin more machines, if needed, using a dashboard from a cloud provider*)